# Add one android project as a library in AOSP App

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, android-build, android-framework

I want to add some features into Browser app by start an activity from another android application. It gives me `package does not exist` while I make the Main Project. Notice that I see the AndroidLib is built successfully into an `out/target/product/generic/data/app/AndroidLib.apk`

Here are two android.mk files:
AndroidLib(a normal Android App)

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
        google-ps \
        android-support-v4 \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
LOCAL_MODULE := AndroidLib
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := AndroidLib

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := google-ps:libs/google-play-services.jar

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

# additionally, build tests in sub-folders in a separate .apk
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Browser App

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
        android-common \
        guava \
        android-support-v13 \
        android-support-v4 \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
        src/com/android/browser/EventLogTags.logtags

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Browser

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

LOCAL_EMMA_COVERAGE_FILTER := *,-com.android.common.*


# We need the sound recorder for the Media Capture API.
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := SoundRecorder, AndroidLib

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
# additionally, build tests in sub-folders in a separate .apk
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Then I do:

```
make -j Browser
```

It gives me:

```
packages/apps/Browser/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java:36: package com.om.AndroidLib does not exist
import com.om.AndroidLib.MainActivity;
```

Comment: Have you declared all the activities of Library Project into main project's Manifest with there package name.And also check the package name decalred in the manifest of your library project.

Comment: @MeenalSharma: I think it should be the same like when you are using Eclipse and define A as Library then Add the library into Main Project. Do I need to copy the declaration of A Lib into Main Project?

Comment: yes you have to copy because you run your main project and not the library,and when the library project's acitivity is called it is acessed from main project.

Comment: `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES` must be separated by space, not comma  (see http://android.mk/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**

Essentially your problem is that the line:

```
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := SoundRecorder, AndroidLib
```

Tells the Android build that your Browser depends on `AndroidLib` being built first, however it will not be linked to `AndroidLib` in any way. To do that you need:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := AndroidLib
```

Except that requires the `AndroidLib` to be a java library project, using the build type:

```
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

And java libraries cannot include resources, unfortunately. And there is no way to link one app to another app in the Android build system.

We are working around that issue frequently, and it is frankly a bit of a mess to do so. But the only workaround we have found is to include all the resources directly in the apps that use those resources. Sorry.

---

**How to make your `AndroidLib` a java library and link to it**

Your android lib should probably be built as a java library, and not as a app package.
So instead of:

```
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

You should probably do:

```
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

Then you lib will be placed in `out/target/product/generic/system/framework/AndroidLib.jar` along with the other system libs.

Also you do not need a `LOCAL_MODULE_NAME` for a lib, it is only applicable for an app. So strip that.

And you should probably consider changing your `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` to:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := user
```

`tests` indicates that you lib should only be built for testing, `user` says to build you lib for all user builds (and implicitly also for engineering builds)

---

In you app `Android.mk` you should then add a line:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := AndroidLib
```

Such that your app will be built with `AndroidLib` in the classpath.

---

In you apps `AndroidManifest.xml` you also need to put a uses library in the `application` tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="AndroidLib" />
```

---

And last you need to create a permissions xml file, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
    <library name="AndroidLib"
            file="/system/framework/AndroidLib.jar"/>
</permissions>
```

And update your product configuration file such that the xml file will be deployed to target:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/XXX/libs/AndroidLib.xml:system/etc/permissions/AndroidLib.xml
```

Replace `device/XXX/libs/` with the path to the permissions xml file.

---

This is how we add and use an Android library in our Android builds. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: I think I didnt make it very clear for you. The android lib is actually an Android Project which has it own Resources. I followed your instruction and I got many R resource not found. I have looked into external/[libraries] and I see they are doing quite similar to what you are saying but they are all pure Java Lib which is not really the case here.

Comment: There are two related kinds of Android libraries. There are the library project type you can create (e.g. in Eclipse) when you are making 3rd party applications. These will be compiled into all the apps that uses them. But when you build the Android OS from source, there is no such concept of an android library project. There is however java libraries which will get installed on target as jar files. But they cannot contain resources, unfortunately. You will have to include the resources you need directly in the app and not the lib, that is currently the only way it will work. Sorry.

Comment: I havent tried your new approach but you gave a vey good explanation. Can we make a symlink from the lib's res to the app instead of copying them over? or can we define LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIRS in the app? I will get back to this. Any way. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @CuongThai: Sure you can make symlinks instead, I am not sure about the LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIRS, you do want to use both the resources from the `Browser` app as well as the `AndroidLib` resources.

Comment: Thank you @BjarkeFreund-Hansen for such a detailed explanation. I was looking for an answer for how to add a jar file to an existing android native project and came across this one. Can you plz suggest if I want to add a jar file, how should I add it?

Comment: @mayurvir: Thanks for the kind words. May I suggest you simply ask a new question about your problems, and somebody (perhaps me) will probably answer you. :)

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen What about this part of base_rule.mk file: "User tags are not allowed anymore -> "http://pastebin.com/HvqRCRJc

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm digging this out of the grave a little bit, but there was never really an answer for how to actually include an Android Library Project (or other apk **with resources**) within an AOSP built application.

Here is what I have done with two projects. "main" is the main application I am building the apk for. "util" is a utility library with resources I am linking against. Both of the projects reside in external/seabold/{package}:

`Android.mk` in seabold/

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

UTIL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/util

UTIL_JAVA_SRC := $(call all-java-files-under, util/src)

#Filter out if the util library isn't present
UTIL_RES_DIR := $(wildcard $(UTIL_PATH)/res)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

`Android.mk` in seabold/main/

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := main

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

#Since the BUILD_PACKAGE makefile expects java files to be relative paths,
#we need to add the ../ in front of each file (which is stored as relative
#to seabold/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(patsubst %.java,../%.java,$(UTIL_JAVA_SRC))

#Make sure both packages' resources are included
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res $(UTIL_RES_DIR)

#Since we are including resouces for two packages (This app and the util lib),
#we need to tell aapt to generate an R.java for the util package as well
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --generate-dependencies --extra-packages com.seabold.util --auto-add-overlay

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Be careful here to make sure you fiddle with the filenames correctly. For me, the files defined in `UTIL_JAVA_SRC` are in the form of `util/src/com/seabold/util/*.java`. Since, the build script for the main app expects java files to be relative paths to the location of `Android.mk`, I'm adding a ../ to properly get to the util library's path.

The key for resources is the LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS. This tells the resource packager to make sure it generates an R.java for the package in the utility library. Without this, all of the utility's resources will get put into the main applications R.java, and the utility classes will fail to compile because its R.java will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

To add a pre-build jar file to the framework I did that:

1. Locate a folder with the jar and the Android.mk file under

   prebuilds/misc/common/

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_MODULE := <jar name> 
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <jar name>.jar 
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES 
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX) 

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

3. Run make on the Android.mk file: `make prebuilds/misc/common/Android.mk`
4. Add the jar file to the frameworks/base/services/Android.mk:

> `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := $(addprefix services.,$(services)) jar-name`

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled over a solution, on how a java library can access resources. The resources are build as a separate apk. The jar-lib can be used from any app that says so in its Manifest. The java-library-code has the `R.java` of the resources-apk and uses `createPackageContext()` to gain access to the actual resources. `createPackageContext()` gets the app-context as parameter which each app must provide whenever it uses a java-lib-function that needs access to the resources.

I'm not that deep into the AOSP-build-system yet, so I'm hoping what I document here makes sense. It's not my solution either, I just improoved on something that some other developer created here at my job so I don't know where he got the approach from.

for the **resource-only-apk** we have:

`Android.mk`

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := shared-resources
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS :=  optional
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR_APPS)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="my.company.common.resources">
<application android:hasCode="false"/>
</manifest>
```

For the **jar-lib** we have:

`Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

####################
# compile the jar  #
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := helper-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

# add package-context-ressources
resource-intermediates := $(call intermediates-dir-for,APPS,shared-resources,,common)
shared_res := $(resource-intermediates)/src/my/company/common/resources/R.java
$(shared_res): $(resource-intermediates)/src/R.stamp
LOCAL_GENERATED_SOURCES := $(shared_res)

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR_JAVA_LIBRARIES)
LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES := helper-lib.xml
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

######################
# deliver permisions #
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := helper-lib.xml
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/etc/permissions
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helper-lib.xml
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.company.helper">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
    <application />
</manifest>
```

`helper-lib.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
    <library name="helper-lib" file="/vendor/framework/helper-lib.jar" />
</permissions>
```

Last but not least here is how we declare them in that over-all-makefile that says what all to include -> `base_packages.mk`

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    my.company.common \
    shared-resources \
    helper-lib
```