# How can I add a 3rd-party library to an Android AOSP build?

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-source

I am trying to add the Jackson JSON library to my AOSP project. I am able to compile my project and flash it to a phone, but I get a runtime error:

```
E/JavaBinder( 1689): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;
...
E/JavaBinder( 1689): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/guice.jar", zip file "/system/framework/beanshell.jar", zip file "/system/framework/services.jar", zip file "/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar", zip file "/system/framework/wifi-service.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have tried including Jackson both from source, and jar. Here are my Android.mk files for each:

---

SOURCE Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,.)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE:= com.fasterxml.jackson.core
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

# Copy XML to /system/etc/permissions/
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := com.fasterxml.jackson.core.xml
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_ETC)/permissions
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

SOURCE `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.xml` (referenced above)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
    <library name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.xml"
        file="/system/framework/com.fasterxml.jackson.jar" />
</permissions>
```

---

JAR Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jackson
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jackson-core-2.5.0.jar
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

---

I have also added a `jackson` entry for in `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES :=` section of the Android.mk file where I want to use Jackson (`frameworks/base/services`). No matter what I've tried, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

**What am I missing? Have I done anything unnecessary?**

Comment: probably duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371626/add-one-android-project-as-a-library-in-aosp-app. Seems that you need to add a dependency to your manifest <uses-library android:name="yourlib" />

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To include a 3rd party library **from source**:

1. copy the library's source into a directory under `$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP/external/` (ex: `$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP/external/jackson`)
2. Create an `Android.mk` file, and place it in the library's folder (ex: `$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP/external/jackson/Android.mk`

   **Contents of Android.mk**:

   ```
   # required (setup the build environment)
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   # optional step to automate some pre-compilation steps for this library
   # run `mvn generate-sources` before we compile
   $(info $(shell (mvn generate-sources -f $(LOCAL_PATH)/pom.xml)))

   # required (the name of the library we are building)
   LOCAL_MODULE := jackson

   # required (paths to all directories that include source code)
   # note the difference between the := (first line) and += (every other line)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src/main)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-java-files-under, target/generated-sources)

   # required (tell the build system what kind of thing we are building)
   include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
   ```
3. Add the library to the `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS` section of your `mk` file. Which file you edit depends on what you are building (ex: `build/target/product/core_minimal.mk`)

   **Original**

   ```
   PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS := \
       okhttp \
       core-junit \
       bouncycastle \
       ext \
       gson
   ```

   **Modified**

   ```
   PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS := \
       okhttp \
       core-junit \
       bouncycastle \
       ext \
       gson \
       jackson
   ```
4. **For each submodule** of your AOSP project (ex: `frameworks/base`), **that you want to have access to the library**, find the makefile (ex: `$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP/frameworks/base/Android.mk` and add an entry for your library to the `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES` line. Example:

   **Original**

   ```
   LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := guice gson
   ```

   **Modified**

   ```
   LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := guice gson jackson
   ```
5. Compile your project.

Comment: Can you please help me with this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114369/two-external-libraries-that-one-depends-on-the-other

Comment: which android version u have used?

Comment: @BharatVankar I wrote this post while working with Android 5.x and 6.x. It may or may not apply to other versions.