# Unknown package name of class file

Tags: java, android, android-source, android.mk

I have two libraries that I want to add to AOSP: 
[Azure Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) &
[Jackson Core](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core)

When Azure Storage depends on Jackson.

Following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186980/how-can-i-add-a-3rd-party-library-to-an-android-aosp-build), I've added both of them under `[MAIN_FOLDER]/external` and with the following `Android.mk` files:

For Jackson -

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := jackson

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug optional

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src/main)

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

and for Azure storage -

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := azure-storage

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := jackson

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug optional

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src/main)

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

When I also added:

```
PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS := \
    jackson \
    azure-storage
```

to my `core_minimal.mk`.

and the following to `[MAIN_FOLDER]/frameworks/base/services/core/Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += jackson azure-storage
```

Alas, when I try to `make update-api && make`, 
I get the following error:

> Error: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/jackson_intermediates/classes.jar: unknown package name of class file com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonLocation.class
>
> Error: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/azure-storage_intermediates/classes.jar: unknown package name of class file com/microsoft/azure/storage/CorsRule.class
>
> make: *** [out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/boot-jars-package-check_intermediates/stamp] Error 1
>
> make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we'd better find where this error comes from, with 'grep' we found it comes from a Python: **build/core/tasks/check_boot_jars/check_boot_jars.py**:

```
def CheckJar(jar):
package_name = os.path.dirname(f)
package_name = package_name.replace('/', '.')
# Skip class without a package name
if package_name and not whitelist_re.match(package_name):
    print >> sys.stderr, ('Error: %s: unknown package name of class file %s' % (jar, f))
    return False
```

Apparently, if your package name not exists in "whitelist_re", you got the error!

"whitelist_re"'s values come from a txt file named "**build/core/tasks/check_boot_jars/package_whitelist.txt**", so the solution is add your package to this whitelist file.

Examples are listed in package_whitelist.txt.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently all libraries have to start with `com.android.`,

so I've added `jarjar-rules.txt` with the following:

```
rule com.microsoft.** com.android.@0
rule com.fasterxml.** com.android.@0
```

and added the following line to `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_JARJAR_RULES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jarjar-rules.txt
```

Now, all the references to `com.microsoft.azure.storage.*` should be changed to `com.android.com.microsoft.azure.storage.*` and the same for `fasterxml`.